# Performance of partial in ExpressJS

Tags: performance, node.js, express

I'm wondering about this:

> NOTE: be careful about when you use partial collections, as rendering
>   an array with a length of 100 means we have to render 100 views. For
>   simple collections you may inline the iteration instead of using
>   partial collection support to decrease overhead.

So it`s not a good idea to do it like this?

```
<%- partial('overall_header.ejs') %>
<!-- Content of the website -->
<%- partial('overall_footer.ejs') %>
```

Or shouldn't I use variables and arrays in partial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Note" that you metioned refers to rendering partial for large arrays, as in guide:

```
partial('comment', comments);
```

Where "comments" is large array.

In your example overall_header and overall_footer are rendered just once, which is fine. No considerable overhead.